# MKTileOverlay in iOS 7 with mbtiles database

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit, mbtiles, mktileoverlay

Is there a way by which I can directly use mbtiles database with MKTileOverlay without using a third party framework like MapBox or any other?

Right now, I have the tiles stored in a folder structure and the code I am using is below:

```
NSString *tileDirectory = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Tiles"];
NSString *tileDirectoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tileDirectory isDirectory:YES];
NSString *tileURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Z{z}/{y}_{x}.png", tileDirectoryURL];
tileOverlay = [[MKTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:tileURL];
[tileOverlay setGeometryFlipped:YES];
[mainMapView addOverlay:tileOverlay];
```

But now I want to have a tiles.mbtiles sqlite database instead of the files in folders.

Please suggest me how can I do this. How do I initialize the MKTileOverlay object if I choose to use sqlite database. How will I put {x},{y},{z}.

I went through the documentation of MKTileOverlay and found that :

```
- (void)loadTileAtPath:(MKTileOverlayPath)path result:(void (^)(NSData *tileData, NSError *error))result
```

can be used but I am not able to understand how can I use it? If any one can please give ma a short example then it would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem and I don't want to use mapbox. Please, any example of use mbtiles without it? In my case, OSMMapKit is not working...Thank you!

Comment: @Eusthace. I was not able to use mbtiles database directly. I had to store the PNGs in the bundle and reference them with the code above in order to render them. But, this was almost a couple years back. Hopefully, there are options available now to do that. I know for a fact that Android can use mbtile database to render the tiles without the use of a third-party library. Also, in the code above, the  geometry flipped property must be set to NO in order for it to work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, but in my case, I don't know why I can't get to work my tiles from maptiler. Do you have a work example? Thank you anyway!

Comment: @eusthace Did you find way to display tiles from database?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at how this project does it…

https://github.com/t2wu/OSMMapKit

It doesn't seem to be finished yet but it should get you on the right path.